# How reference works in autoreferenced data structures?

Tags: java, data-structures

If i have a simple linked list in this case

```
     class Node{
         int data;
         Node next;
     }
```

And i implement a method called addNode(Node head, int data) that factorize the head node, thus i need to return the head.

```
     class LinkedList{
         public Node addNode(Node head, int data){
             Node tmpnode = new Node();
             tmpnode.data = data;

             if(head == null)
                 return tmpnode;

             Node cnode = head; //why i need to add this line

             for(;cnode.next != null; cnode = cnode.next);

             cnode.next = tmpnode;
             return head;
         }
     }
```

I studied data structures in java and c, but i implemented an interface called Copyable, that returns a new instance of one object.

My question is if i remove this line [Node cnode = tmpnode;] and i iterate the head node and find the final node to add a new node, why the initial pointer is not preserved?

```
     for(;head.next != null; head = head.next);
     head.next = tmpnode;
     return head;
```

It works different in structures that are not self-referenced, for example:

```
     class Shirt{char size;}
```

In this fragment of code i create one object, and two variables that are pointing to the same reference, prints the same result:

```
     {
         Shirt s1 = new Shirt();
         Shirt s2 = s1;
         s1.size = 'S';
         System.out.println(s1.size); //S
         System.out.println(s2.size); //S

     }
```

In the example described before: what is the difference with an auto-referenced Node data type?

Comment: I read your question twice and I'm still not sure what you're asking.  Do you mean to ask why `head` doesn't point to the first Node in your list anymore if you make the change you suggest?  The answer to that would simply be:  Because you're using head to walk your list with `for(;head.next != null; head = head.next);`, assigning a new value to `head` at each element until the end of the list, and then return 'head'.  Btw there would be nothing wrong with using a `while` loop instead of abusing a `for` loop like that :P

Comment: A for can be use like any loop, is the same :P, but what happens when i assign Node cnode = head, cnode points to the same reference?

Comment: I think this method doesn't do what you want either way.  It returns a reference to the new Node when the list is empty (`head == null`), which is good of course. But if you pass it an existing list, it makes a new reference `cnode` to the new Node `tmpnode` and starts traversing it.  That's not a long walk, a new Node's `next` is `null`.  Then it makes `cnode.next` reference `tmpnode`, creating a circular list of one element. And then it returns head.  I'd be surprised if the item was added to the list just by juggling local variables that are never pointing at the list you pass with `head`.

Comment: Sorry it was this line [Node cnode = head;], i had a mistake in my code.